# Likelihood ratio test for mixed effects model

Tags: mixed-model, variance, likelihood, likelihood-ratio

I'm currently struggling with how to assess the type I error of a permutation test for significance of variance term in R. The idea that I want to follow is outlined below:

Suppose we simulate data such that $$Y_{ij}=1+b_i+\epsilon_{ij}$$ where $b_i\sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma_b^2)$ and $\epsilon_{ij} \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma_e^2)$. We can then calculate the LRT statistic for this model (testing against the alternative of $\sigma_e^2 \neq 0$) and permute the clusters (that is, the values of the $b_i$'s) to see how does the LRT vary across the different permutations.

I was, in particular, interested in the type I error of this test, i.e. what happens if we indeed have $\sigma_b^2=0$, but the issue I'm facing is that when using the lmer() function in R I get an error as I am simulating $b_i=0$ for all $i$ and I'm assuming the model becomes unidentifiable. Is there a way to make this work, as in, how should the code of the model look like?

I should point out that I'd prefer to have just hints, not full answers as this is related to something important that will be marked and I want to be a decent human being and not rely on good people on the internet.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My first hint is to use `lmer` from the `lme4` package, not `lme`. When the variance components approach zero it will be more likely to converge without errors, although it may (and should) give a singular fit warning.

My second hint is to simulate $b_i$ with $\sigma_b^2$ not as identically zero, but just very small.

Comment: First of all, thank You for taking the time to comment! Secondly, I had made a mistake - I did in fact used lmer(). Also, I tried to use small value such as 0.0001 for $\sigma_b^2$ and although it still gives a warning, the procedure can be carried out. Thanks once again!

Comment: Happy to help. I would also play around with different sample sizes (numbers of clusters and numbers of observations per cluster)